# Facebook Data deletion for Unity

Tags: unity, facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my unity game using the facebook sdk. In order to test this, I need to change the status of my app in fb developers site from "development" to "live". But in order to do so, fb is asking me to update "Data Deletion Request Callback" field (screen shot below). Can someone please help with this as I don't know how to implement this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the link behind "Learn More"?

Comment: ya...it's not that helpful...here is the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/data-deletion-callback

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is that you don't understand or need help implementing? The more precisely you can identify the problem, the faster you'll tend to get answers, and the more helpful those answers will be because they're able to target the specific parts you need most.

Comment: the thing is I'm completely lost with this. I haven't done this before....how do I get started with this...

Comment: Well, which route do you want to go? Do you want to provide a tool inside your game that deletes users' data, and share a web URL with instructions about how to use that in-game tool? Or do you want to provide a separate deletion service through which Facebook can request deletion for a particular user via a callback URL? Either one is a valid solution - which one is appropriate for your game?

Comment: I would like to implement the Data Deletion Request Callback instead of the web URL with instructions.

Comment: after spending a few hours trying to figure this out, I have decided not to implement this for the time being...